# The Dynamic import for angularjs + webpack

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, webpack

I'm trying to implement Webpack4 for the angularjs project. I created some entrypoints and as for static imports they works as it's expected. But in the project we have some landing pages and their folders with the same names ('1300', '1520') etc that includes landing page css and html files. So if we use url like '...?theme=1520' the html and css from the '1520' folder are used(along with general styles and html). Now I have 3 webpack bundles for custom js, vendor js, general css.
So I try to import the landing page css and html dynamically depending on the url parameter. Of course, it doesn't work even after using all the plugins and solutions that I could find everywhere. The main goal now is to insert landing page css styles dynamically into the css bundle(**in css.js**). Thanks!

webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const ImageminWebpWebpackPlugin = require("imagemin-webp-webpack-plugin");
const { nodeName } = require("jquery");


module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    //mode: 'production',
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'WebContent'),
    entry: {
        custom: './js/app.js',
        styles: './js/css.js',
        vendor: './js/vendor.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
        //,publicPath: 'build'
    },
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
        assetNameRegExp: /\.bundle\.css$/g,
        cssProcessor: cssnano,
        cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
            preset: ['default', { discardComments: { removeAll: true } }],
        },
        canPrint: false
    }),
    new ImageminWebpWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                  loader: 'babel-loader',
                  options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import']
                  }
                }
              },
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                loader: 'html-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [{
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    options: {
                        publicPath: './WebContent',
                        esModule: true
                    }
                }, {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        import: true,
                        //modules: true
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'images/',
                        publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, './build/images/'),
                        //emitFile: false
                    }
                },
                    'url-loader?limit=100000']
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            //    chunks: 'all',
            cacheGroups: {
                styles: { 
                    name: 'styles.bundle',
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    chunks: 'all',
                    enforce: true,
                    minChunks: 1
                }
            }
        }
        ,
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
            extractComments: false,
            exclude: /\/node_modules/,
            terserOptions: {
                keep_fnames: true,
                mangle: false
            },
        })]
    }
};
```

css.js:

```
var BORDER_SCREEN_WIDTH_VALUE = 768;
var device = 'mobile';
var path = '';
var lpNumber = new RegExp('[\?&]theme=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.search)[1];
if (window.innerWidth > BORDER_SCREEN_WIDTH_VALUE) {
    device = 'desktop';
}

path = '/' + lpNumber + '/' + device + '/';
console.log(path);
import(/* webpackIgnore: true */'../WebContent/LP' + path + 'style.css').then((module) => { 
    module();
});

require('../css/amazing-theme.min.css');
require('../css/general.min.css');
require('../css/leadgen-theme.min.css');
require('../css/partials.min.css');
require('../css/style-all.min.css');
//require('../LP/1138/desktop/style.css');
```